# Emacs screwing up encoding on recovering from autosave

Tags: emacs, encoding, utf-8

I had been cheerfully hacking away on a UTF-8 file in emacs (version 23.3.1) when I was called away from my computer.  When I returned, my session (it was on a remote system) had closed, so I logged back in and re-opened my file.  As might be expected, I was alerted there was a more recent auto-saved version, and did I want to restore that?  Sure.

When it pulled in the auto-saved version, all my high-bit characters, which had previously been showing fine on the screen, were converted into number strings that I assume were references to code points or something; when I attempted to save, emacs then threw the encoding error that it couldn't save with the present encoding.

Particularly irritating was that when I opened the auto-saved version in emacs directly, the encoding was correct (well, apparently so -- my high-bit characters all appeared correctly).

Why, when I attempted to recover the file, even though apparently the autosaved file was in the right encoding, did emacs get confused about my encoding and choke?  Or more to the point: how do I get emacs to not do that anymore, and to keep everything in UTF-8 where it belongs?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: What version of Emacs?

Comment: @JustinWood Emacs 23.3.1.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @phils, is there some alternative way of reporting a bug in emacs that doesn't entail exposing my email address to the public?  M-x report-emacs-bug looks really toxic that way.

Comment: Offhand I don't know.